# DbGeometry makevalid?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

I'm new to this. I don't know how to use the SqlSpatialFunction MakeValid.
I have a DbGeometry which is a polygon. This polygon is not valid and I want to
make it valid.

Can anyone explain how to use the MakeValid method?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlspatialfunctions.makevalid.aspx)

Comment: In the query you would use `SqlSpatialFunctions.MakeValid(dbGeometryValue)`. If this does not work for you be more specific what you want to achieve and show what you have tried.

Comment: See this question the last answer may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640565/is-there-something-like-dbgeometry-makevalid-in-net-4-5/16757876#16757876

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Going off of what Pawel commented, All I do is check to see if it is valid then make it valid if it isn't.

```
DbGeometry myGeometry = DbGeometry.FromText("POLYGON ((10 10, 15 15, 5 15, 10 15, 10 10))");
if(!myGeometry.IsValid)
{
    myGeometry = SqlSpatialFunctions.MakeValid(myGeometry);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `SqlSpatialFunctions.MakeValid` on DbGeometry, and if you do, it will throw the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException : This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.
```

Therefore, what you can do is to make it valid using its WKT string and then convert that valid string toa DBGeometry like this:

```
public static DbGeometry MakeValid(DbGeometry geom)
{
     if (geom.IsValid)
          return geom;

     var wkt = SqlGeometry.STGeomFromText(new SqlChars(geom.AsText()), 0).MakeValid().STAsText().ToSqlString().ToString();
     return DbGeometry.FromText(wkt, 0);
}
```